# Generate certificate with very few information using OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, certificate

I would like to generate a certificate with only a few information to get a very small certificate, maybe just the Version, Serial Number, Issuer, Validaty, Public Key and the signature.

I am asking this because the certificate I have just generated using openssl has about 900Bytes which is too much for the purposes I want.

I want a certificate to use with ecdsa 256 with nistp256.

Comment: Why 900 Bytes is too much for the purpose? Are you taking it in DER format? I think it is a reasonable size.

Comment: The problem is that I am going to be transmitting a packet which will carry the certificate inside. and the packet is sent over the network each 100ms, so this will cause a huge overhead on the network to attach the certificate in each packet. I would like to know if it is possible to generate smaller certificate sizes for that purpose. I have about 900bytes certificate in PEM format and about 700 in DER format.

Comment: You might be able to send the certificate once and thereafter send a cryptographic hash of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not you consider some good compression algorithm to reduce the size?

Or you can reduce the key size to reduce the overall size. As far as I know, you can generate minimal certificate with some basic information (Version, Serial Number, Issuer, Subject, Validity, public key and signature are required). You can omit the extensions and keep these fields too small.

To reduce the size, you can reduce the size of these information. However, version (as governed by standard), serial number, issuer (governed by issuer authority) and validity are not in your control. Signature is also depends on signer's public key which may not be in your control (unless you are signing yourself or using self-signed certificate) as it depends on size of the signing private key and hashing algorithm.

Only things in your control are subject (you may on your choice can keep it very small) and public key (you can choose size and algorithm but that may compromise the security or issuer may not allow).

Over and above,  you can use some compression if that can reduce the size of certificate significantly.